# tapestry strange behaviour

Tags: java, tapestry

Well, at least it seems as tapestry issue.

I'm getting an exception when trying to access a specific page:

```
org.apache.tapestry.PageNotFoundException: 
      Page 'ASpecificPage' not found in application namespace.
```

Seems like some pages are found, and some are not, I'm new to this project, and so far cannot say is there any difference between them.

The error still occurs, even when whole jboss-4 instance, along with the deployed application, is copied from my coworkers' computers and run, whereas they do not experience such problems.  Supposedly there is no other application-specific configuration, and it's all contained within the server instance.

Any ideas? Even not Tapestry-related? I tried using same java version, with update number precision, but in vain. Like, where should I start to debug?

EDIT:

I'm new to tapestry, so if anything is missing or just inaccurate, just let me know. Some details:

- the application is deployed as war, copied to deploy directory,
  unexploded
- there are other jars copied as well, not sure if they are relevant
- when searching for ASpecificPage, it seems that there is only a java
  class (i.e. ASpecificPage.java), and there is missing appropriate
  .html file
- when searched in code, I found occurences like:

  clearPopUp(cycle);
  ASpecificPage page=(ASpecificPage) cycle.getPage("ASpecificPage");
  page.show(cycle, ASpecificPage.TAB_2);

Any other details needed?

Comment: Can you give some information about your package and folder stucture, and where is your file and whats the one it says missing

Comment: Due to lack of formatting in comments, I just updated the question itself, please have a look at it